# PHP Image Optimize without EXEC

Tags: php, image, compression

I want to optimize a JPG image (lossless compression) to satisfy Google Page Speed, but I do not want to use this function:

```
exec("someBashCommand")
```

Every script that I found uses this function, but it is banned on my server.

Is it possible to do with pure PHP?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ImageMagick with PHP, like this:

```
<?php
    $img = new Imagick("image.jpg"); 
    $img->setImageCompression (imagick::COMPRESSION_LOSSLESSJPEG);
    $img->writeImage('result.jpg');
?>
```

but I have no idea how it is likely to help optimise anything if you are not prepared to allow some degree of quality tradeoff for size.

Answer (score 0):

You could install the PageSpeed Module on your server:

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module

but I am afraid that's also banned on your server.

But know that you don't have to optimize images ON your server, you can do it BEFORE you upload the images to the server. The only exception would be images uploaded by users of your website.

Use any image program with enough options for saving images to imitate what Google wants you to do. There's nothing mysterious about it, it can all be done in normal software. For instance:

http://www.practicalecommerce.com/articles/71090-15-Tools-to-Optimize-Ecommerce-Images

But remember these packages may not satisfy Googles demands.

Do not overdo this. Google shows you the best possible optimization, according to the rules they set, but your site will work fine even if Google thinks it could be slightly better.

Comment: Yes, Images are unfortunatelly uploaded by users.

Comment: Well, in that case the only other option is using another webhoster so you can do what's needed. (Yes, I like stating the obvious).